# Problem with Swap file Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sudo, swap

I have created a new user, write on /etc/sudoers - `echo '<USERNAME> ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL'`  , then I login my new user, and try to swap files with the following command:

> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=64M count=16; sudo mkswap /swapfile; sudo swapon /swapfilesudo mkswap /swapfilesudo swapon /swapfile

And i see this error

> swapon: /swapfilesudo: stat falied: No such file or directory
>   swapon: mkswap: stat falied: No such file or directory
>   swapon: /swapfilesudo: stat falied: No such file or directory
>   swapon: swapon: stat falied: No such file or directory
>   swapon: /swapfile: stat falied: No such file or directory

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it more legible. Paragraphs are your friend. In fact, whitespace is in general, you want `sudo swapon /swapfile` not `sudo swapon /swapfilesudo`.

Comment: I edited it as best I could, but it could use a little more @ODIN.

Answer (score 1):

The commands you copy-pasted here are messed up. Enter them one by one and it should work:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=64M count=16
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

You can check if it worked with:

```
swapon -s
```

It should show something like:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        1048572 0   -1
```

If you want the swap file to be persistent after a reboot, you also need to add it to /etc/fstab.